# Back Button Different on Different Navigation View Controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have searched and can't figure out what is going on.
I have a NavController set up to root on VC1 which has a push segue to VC2. On VC2 the stock back button is just the Arrow Icon (no Arrow Icon with "Back Text). 
In a different part of my app I have another Navigation Controller set up to root on VC5 which pushes to VC6. On VC6, the stock back button is the Arrow Icon with the "Back" text).

I am trying to be uniform but I can't figure out how to change these without loading in my own images (which I really don't want to do). I have tried to look for differences between the Navigation View Controllers but can't find how they are different.

Preferably I would just like the Arrow Icon without the "Back" Text.

Anyone experience this?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: You can control the text on the back button by setting the title of the view controller you came from.

```
  self.title = @"my title";
```

And this text will appear on the back button of the next view controller you will navigate to. (Unless you defined an image for the back button)

This is not the best solution, (I prefer faviomob's solution using the storyboard, or programmatically), but it can be convenient in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my picture. When I select any cell in the table view (in root view controller), the second view controller pushed with '111' back button. So, to have empty text there just set it to whitespace.

[image]

[image]

Comment: All of my "root view controllers" don't have any text in the Back field. Some  still have the "Back" text

Answer (score 0):

To set just the back arrow set the left bar Button item of the Navigation bar. Follow this:

```
//Set the back image. Use ur own image instead of back.png.
UIBarButtonItem* leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"back.png"]
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(leftBarButtonPressed)];

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBarButton];
```

Comment: Here self is the UIVIewController.